# Webdriver instances not created for custom protractor.conf file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, travis-ci

I want to integrate my E2E suite in Travis, so I followed [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/angular-6-travis-ci-with-headless-chrome-58fab1b394e1) article. As mentioned in the article I've created a custom `protractor.ci.conf.js` file of the Travis build. I've placed this file inside my `e2e` folder (path: `e2e/protractor.ci.conf.js`).

The only difference in my custom `e2e/protractor.ci.conf.js` and angular generated `protractor.conf.js` files is the value in `args` property displayed below.

**e2e/protractor.ci.conf.js**

```
chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--headless',
        'window-size=1920,1080'
      ]
    }
```

**protractor.conf.js**

```
const SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
   './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2,
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--start-maximized']
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'localhost:4000/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
    print: function () {
    }
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.json'
    });
  }
};
```

In my `package.json` file there are 2 scripts one for running tests **locally** and one on **Travis**.

**Package.json** (at the same level where **protractor.conf.js** is located)

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "ng test --watch=false",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "concurrently --kill-others \"ng e2e --port=4000\" \"npm run _server:run\"",
    "e2e:ci": "concurrently --kill-others \"ng e2e --port=4000 --protractor-config=e2e/protractor.ci.conf.js\" \"npm run _server:run\"",
    "_server:run": "tsc -p ./server && concurrently \"tsc -w -p ./server\" \"nodemon dist/server/index.js\" ",
    ...
  },
```

**.travis.yml**

```
branches:
 only:
  - staging
  - prod
  - functional-testing
 script:
   ...
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE == *"[skip e2e]"* ]]; then echo "skipping E2E test"; else npm run e2e:ci; fi
  ...
before_deploy:
  - sed -i '/dist/d' .gitignore
  - git add . && git commit -m "latest build"
  - cd $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/dist
```

**PROBLEM**

When simply running `npm run e2e`, every test is working fine. But when I'm using `npm run e2e:ci` command scripts hangs and no instance of WebDriver runs.

> I/launcher — Running 0 instances of WebDriver

is coming instead of 1 or 2 instances.

Comment: could you share your configuration file for Travis? Also why do you need `concurrently --kill-others`? Also could you change `\" with &&?

Comment: @Oleksii I've added `.yml` file script. Please check

Comment: @Oleksii it's added because it will concurrently run two task (instead of running them in two different terminals) and if any one of the process (frontend or server) dies, it will end the other too, because the other one will be of no use then

Comment: @Oleksii I've tried with `&&` also. But it still hangs 

Comment: @Oleksii I have also added full `protractor.conf.js` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because since you made a new config file and apparently placed in the folder 
`/e2e` instead of the default root folder.

The path to the test files in your case should also be updated.

So `'./e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'` will get changed to `'./**/*.e2e-spec.ts'`

Since, currently the test is not able to find any files specified, it doesn't run any instances.

Comment: Ohh Thanks, @Manzur sir you have just saved my life today. What a stupid mistake I did 